# Active storage has_many_attached is purging previous uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to add more files to a has_many_attached, but when I upload a new file the previous file is purged. Uploading multiple files does add multiple files, but they are all purged on the next upload as well. Is this intended behavior? if so, how do I prevent the purging?

log.rb

```
class Log < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :uploads
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @log, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :uploads, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please have a look into this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35817

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent overwriting the existing attachments by adding the following line to `config/environments/development.rb`, `config/environments/test.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`, as kindly indicated by [quantavi](https://github.com/quantavi) in [this issue](https://github.com/richardvenneman/trestle-active_storage/issues/41): https://github.com/richardvenneman/trestle-active_storage/issues/41

```
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

Apparently in Rails 6 the default behavior when uploading files again is to purge the previously uploaded files. You can find a longer thread about it [in this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35817) which [Aarthi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8785865/aarthi) linked in a comment. The line above changes this setting so that consecutive uploads append files instead of overwriting the old ones.

(As you may have inferred from the link to the issue I ran into the same issue when using the Trestle admin panel with the complementary trestle-active_storage gem, that adds active storage field support.)

Answer (score 1):

I kept my old assets with an hidden_field tag like this:

```
<% @product.photos.each do |ph| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :photos, multiple: true, value: ph.signed_id %>
<% end %>
```

This worked for me

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work. I added the hidden fields next to the file_field, but the existing attachments were still replaced by the new upload when the form was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ruby on Rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#replacing-vs-adding-attachments), Rails automatically replaces any existing attachments when using a `has_many_attached` association.

The solution is to use a hidden field with the image's `signed_id`, as follows:

```rb
<% if @object.images.attached? %>
  <% @object.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :images, multiple: true, value: image.signed_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

Comment: Being forced to put in some duds like this makes me think rails has lost something .
How come the  "replace_on_assign_to_many " config is not working ?